# How to calculate the distance between two points on a unit sphere?

Tags: spatial

I have got this formula for spherical distance i.e. istance of the shortest path along the surface of the sphere on the wolfram alpha site:- 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalDistance.html

But is there any reference or standard textbook where I can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a complex formula to prove.

If you have two points on a sphere of radius $r$, the shortest distance between them lies on a great circle - a circle with the same radius and center as the sphere, that passes through those two points.

What we want to find is now the distance between two points on a circle of radius $r$, following the circle. By definition, that's the angle between the vectors formed from the center to each of these points, in radians, times the radius of the circle.

Now, how do we find that angle? Well, we remember that the dot product between two vectors $A$ and $B$ can be written as $A \bullet B = \|A\|\cdot\|B\|\cdot cos(\theta)$, with theta being the angle between the two vectors.

The vectors are of norm r (because they're on the circle of radius r), so we have $cos(\theta) = \frac{A \bullet B}{r^2}$.

Hence the distance you're looking for is $cos^{-1}(\frac{A \bullet B}{r^2}) \cdot r$

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful, but do you have any reference in mind i.e. any standard textbooks? Actually I have used this concept in a paper but this is not the focus, so just want to show a reference instead of proving it.

Comment: I'd suggest  http://www.navlab.net/Publications/A_Nonsingular_Horizontal_Position_Representation.pdf , it seems to be what you are looking for, as a reference (this is the one the wikipedia article quotes, eh).
Other than that, no idea for a real reference.. I personally would state it and put the proof in an appendix if the reader is curious for a demonstration.